# Regarding Execution of Apex class

Tags: apex

```
public Class CreatingAccount
{
public Account createAccount(string name)  
{
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = name;
system.debug(name);
return acc;
}
}
```

**How to execute the class in developer console using Anonymus Window**

Comment: Please Guide me for the Answer

Answer (score 2):

Press **Ctrl+E** on Developer Console,

Within the opened Window, write this

```
CreatingAccount ca = new CreatingAccount();
ca.createAccount('Name of Account');
```

and press the **Execute** Button